# Select query does not retrieve info from db after insert into query

Tags: c#, select, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, insert-into

I've built an app in vs 2012 that is supposed to be able to select, insert, update, delete info from a sql server 2012 database. At first I put some data into the db using sql server. I built my select queries to test them out and they worked. After this I built my insert query and tested it out. It also works. But if I try to retrieve data that I have inserted, it doesn't retrieve anything.

Here's an example of one of my select queries:

```
    query = "SELECT P.Denumire, P.Pret, P.Cantitate, P.Reducere, P.Pret_redus, " +
                 "S.Stoc_magazin, S.Stoc_depozit " +
             "FROM Produse P, Stoc_intern S " +
             "WHERE S.ID_produs IN " +
                 "(SELECT P.ID_produs " +
                  "FROM Produse " +
                  "WHERE P.Denumire LIKE '%" + tb_s_name.Text + "%')";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, c);
    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    q_res.DataSource = dt;
```

And here's and example of one of my insert queries:

```
    query = "Insert INTO Produse " +
               "(Denumire, Pret, Cantitate, Reducere) " +
               "Values(@Denumire, @Pret, @Cantitate, @Reducere)";
    SqlCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand();
    cmd.Connection = c;
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Denumire", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = tb_op_name.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pret", SqlDbType.Float).Value = tb_op_pv.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cantitate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = tb_op_cantitate.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reducere", SqlDbType.Float).Value = tb_op_red.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Both queries work, it's just that if I submit the insert query and after try to select something with the select query, it does not retrieve anything although the information exists in the database. I checked by opening the db in sql server after executing the insert query from my vs built app.

Here's the connection string also:

```
    SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\DB\Supermarket.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Connect Timeout=30");
```

Comment: Can you show us the **connection string** you're using, please?

Comment: Use int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); and check the value of I after it runs. If its zero then no rows were inserted.

Comment: I added the connection string @marc_s. I verified to see what value the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() has after execution and it is 1, so a row is affected, and like I said, the insertion works. The select does not retrieve what was inserted however.

Comment: Does the select return rows in SSMS?

Comment: Yes, it works in SSMS @BrianP.

Answer (score 0):

Please use different SqlConnections for each procedure.